# TLS client authentication support in System.Net.Security.SslStream - how to submit acceptable client cert CA names?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tls1.3

[System.Net.Security.SslStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=net-5.0) supports TLS client certificates by requesting it as follows:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(
    serverCertificate,
    clientCertificateRequired: true,
    checkCertificateRevocation: true);
```

This works well, however, the client (the browser) will send a TLS client certificate of its own choosing. The TLS protocol supports the server submitting a list of "acceptable client certificate CA names". Without providing one, the client is free to choose one. The list of CAs is important as it is the only way to reliably work with cases where the clint has multiple client certificates installed. I do not see how I can submit a list using this class.

Is this a limitation or am I missing something? Are there workarounds?

Comment: Your server code has to check client response against all certificate to find which certificate the client is using.

Comment: The client does not volunteer all its identities. The server requests an appropriate client certificate from the client. RFC 2246 7.4.4. "A non-anonymous server can optionally request a certificate from the client (...) certificate_authorities: A list of the distinguished names of acceptable certificate authorities."

Comment: There is a .net client side callback on the same class through "acceptableListeners" no way for the server side to set it.

Comment: A certificate is never sent!!! A key exchange is done where a test message is encrypted and sent and then the server validates the encrypted message.

Comment: The private key is not sent but the Public Key Certificate, commonly referred to as certificate, is sent. Let us stay on topic please.